# error installing lxml on ec2

Tags: python, gcc, amazon-ec2, lxml

Having trouble installing lxml on an amazon ec2 instance.

Can you possibly help me figure this out? I think it might be a problem with the way gcc installed based on the wordsize.h issue, but I have no idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ sudo pip install lxml
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.3.0.tar.gz (3.4MB): 3.4MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:8:0:
    /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1:27: fatal error: bits/wordsize.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python27 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-_eECL7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Building lxml version 3.3.0.

Building without Cython.

Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26

Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:8:0:

/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1:27: fatal error: bits/wordsize.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python27 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-_eECL7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: You are likely missing a -dev package which includes the missing header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not finding your platform specific include files. i.e. bits/wordsize.h

Check that you have the following directory:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits
```

If it exists try the the following

```
cd /usr/include
ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/* .
```

If the files don't exist try:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

If you are using CentOS or Redhat

```
yum install glibc-devel glibc-headers
```

Comment: I think you are close but I don't have that directory, and I have yum and not apt-get

Comment: If you are using CentOS or RedHat the files would be under /usr/include/bits . Check the edit above and try running the `yum` command

Comment: the error went away after I installed the glibc-devel and glibc-headers, but now i am getting a new error:     /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:6:25: fatal error: pyconfig-64.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Try `yum install python-devel`

Comment: I rolled back to python2.6

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install lxml in a Python 3 virtualenv, you'll need to install `python34-devel` rather than just `python-devel`:

`sudo yum install python34-devel`